# Sub directories under checkpoint directory for spark structured streaming

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

The checkpoint directory for spark structured streaming create four sub directories. What are each of them for?

```
/warehouse/test_topic/checkpointdir1/commits
/warehouse/test_topic/checkpointdir1/metadata
/warehouse/test_topic/checkpointdir1/offsets
/warehouse/test_topic/checkpointdir1/sources
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the StreamExecution class doc:

```
/**
   * A write-ahead-log that records the offsets that are present in each batch. In order to ensure
   * that a given batch will always consist of the same data, we write to this log *before* any
   * processing is done.  Thus, the Nth record in this log indicated data that is currently being
   * processed and the N-1th entry indicates which offsets have been durably committed to the sink.
   */
  val offsetLog = new OffsetSeqLog(sparkSession, checkpointFile("offsets"))

  /**
   * A log that records the batch ids that have completed. This is used to check if a batch was
   * fully processed, and its output was committed to the sink, hence no need to process it again.
   * This is used (for instance) during restart, to help identify which batch to run next.
   */
  val commitLog = new CommitLog(sparkSession, checkpointFile("commits"))
```

Metadata log is for information related to the query. e.g in KafkaSource it is used to write the starting offsets of the query(offset for each partition)

Comment: Need some clarity of sources folder as well. I know the post is too old but is there anyone active on this thread. Please explain. Thanks

Comment: Also, as per above explaination "MetaData" stores the starting offset of the query but as I checked my folder it has content like "{"id":"3b7f07a0-2256-4097-83d4-dfeab6cf56cd"}" . I am not sure what this hex stands for . Can you explain this also with example.

Answer (score 0):

Source folder contains the Initial kafka offset values of each partition.
like if your kafka has 3 partitions 1,2,3 and starting values for each partition is 0 then it will contain value like {1:0,2:0,3:0}